# Change appearance of natbib \cite locally

Tags: tables, citing, natbib

I am sorry if this question has already been addressed somewhere; it appears my Google Fu is weak with respect to this question.

## The Problem

I am trying to create a table that compiles experimental data. My aim is to include the reference in a separate column, so as to distinguish it from the values in other columns. The problem that I now have is that the references generated still are formatted the same as in normal text (superscript). This is highly unpractical for use in the table, as the font size in it will also be smaller than normal text.

### Minimum working example

Here is a MWE that demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,oneside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english]{babel}        
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                        
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
            marginparwidth=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage[super, sort&compress]{natbib}


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
The influence of rings\cite{ref1} must not be neglected when examining this or 
the other. Furthermore, acting is a career choice that should always be held in 
high regard.\cite{ref2}

\section{The Table}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \caption{This is the table that I am talking about. All the time.}
    \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \hline \hline
    Field name & Value & Ref. \\
    \hline
    Arg1 & 122.3 & \cite{ref1} \\
    Arg2 & 129.4 & \cite{ref2} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\footnotesize
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}

\end{document}
```

biblio.bib:

```
@article{ref1,
    author    = {Hermann Hesse},
    title     = "The Things about Annular Rings",
    journal   = "Journal of Rings",
    year      = "2064"
}
@article{ref2,
    author={Julia Roberts},
    title={Acting: A Career},
    journal = {Journal of Acting Reviews},
    pages={20--23},
    year=1997
}
```

### Output

[image: Output of the MWE above.]

### Desired Output

I'd like the table to look like the following:

[image: Desired output]

Generally it would be great to have some new type of command like `\tablecite{}` which would then not superscript the reference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `natbib` provides `\citenum` macro.

Comment: See the natbib documentation 2.4 Extended Citation Commands.

Comment: Wow, `\citenum` totally achieves what I want! Thanks for the help.